# to Global Variables inside functions

Tags: php, function, variables, global

I have problem to Global Variables inside functions

```
<?php
    function main(){
        $var = "My Variable";
        function sub() {
            GLOBAL $var;
            echo $var; // Will show "My Variable"
        }
        sub();
        echo $var; // Will show "My Variable" 
    }
    main();
    sub(); // Will not show and I will sub() cant use outside main() function
?>
```

1. I just want to global `$var` inside sub functions
2. `sub()` will not work outside `main()` function

I tied to use `GLOBAL` but it show nothing ... Any ?

Comment: define variable outside of function ?

Comment: yes , outside `main()` @NullPointer

Comment: All functions and all  variables inside `main()` will not work outside `main()` @NullPointer

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Ok , I will expand , just a min

Comment: Your example works as you think it should at my machine. The first `echo` does not show anything, because the global `$var` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand what you want, but your `$var` is not global. its a local variable inside main()

a variable is only global, if you declare it outside of a function or class.

```
<?php
    $var = "My Variable"; // made $var global
    function main(){
        //removed $var here
        function sub() {
            global $var;
            echo $var; // Will show "My Variable"
        }
        sub();
        echo $var; // Will throw notice:  Undefined variable: var
    }
    main();
    sub(); // Will show "My Variable"
?>
```

why would you declare a method inside a method to call it from there?

maybe something like this is what you want...

```
<?php
   //$var = "My Variable";
    function main(){
        $var = "My Variable";
        $sub = function($var) {
            echo "sub: ".$var; // Will show "sub: My Variable"
        };
        $sub($var);
        echo "main: ".$var; //  Will show "main: My Variable"
    }
    main();
    // sub(); // Will not work
    // $sub(); // Will not work
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think last one is ok for me

Answer (score 1):

You do not assing a value to the global scope variable `$var`.
Only `main()` assigns a value to a variable called `$var` but only in `main()`'s scope. And only `main()`'s `echo $var;` actually prints the value. Both calls to `sub()` do not produce output.
try it with

```
<?php
function main(){
    $var = "My Variable"; 
    function sub() {
      GLOBAL $var;
      echo 'sub: ', $var, "\n";
    }
    sub();
    echo 'main: ', $var, "\n";
}
main();
sub();
```

the output is

```
sub: 
main: My Variable
sub:
```

and please have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection ;-)

Comment: Ok, in you example I will output is "sub: My Variable , main: My Variable , sub: "

Comment: 1. last line `sub()` will not work , coz this func is outside `main()`

Comment: Yes, it will show the contents of the global $var, which has no value assigned to it, therefore the output is blank. see http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pgs-w78